# Java sockets: updating on client but not server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serialization

So I'm trying to make game for android using multithreading on the server side, and I'm trying  to update the player's x and y by using writeObject(x), writeObject(y) (x and y are hashmaps of all the player's x/y).  I keep getting no errors but the server and client x differ.

Everything works in the AsyncTask but when I try to update the x and y, only the client gets updated.

Client AsyncTask:

```
public class internetRoutesRetrieve extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {

            MyClient = new Socket("myip", myport);

            input = new ObjectInputStream(MyClient.getInputStream());
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(MyClient.getOutputStream());

            while ((fromServer = input.readObject()) != null) {

                if (fromServer.getClass.equals(HashMap.class) {

                    if (((HashMap) fromServer).get(Integer.toString(0)).getClass().equals(Float.class)) {

                        thisFloatArray = (HashMap<String, Float>) fromServer;

                        if (thisFloatArray.get("0").equals((float) 1)) {

                            System.out.println("playerX: " + fromServer);
                            playerX = (HashMap<String, Float>) fromServer;

                        } else if (thisFloatArray.get("0").equals((float) 2)) {

                            System.out.println("playerY: " + fromServer);
                            playerY = (HashMap<String, Float>) fromServer;

                        }

                    } else if (((HashMap) fromServer).get(Integer.toString(0)).getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {

                        thisIntegerArray = (HashMap<String, Integer>) fromServer;

                        if (thisIntegerArray.get("0").equals(clientMax)) {

                            System.out.println("clientArray: " + fromServer);
                            clientArray = thisIntegerArray;
                            init();

                        }
                    }
```

Works Great.  Then I try to update the playerX/Y:

```
Runnable drawAll = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {

            if (mode == DRAG) {

                playerX.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), playerX.get(Integer.toString(clientNum))+playerSpeed);
                playerY.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), playerY.get(Integer.toString(clientNum))+playerSpeed);

                DrawView.pMatrixArray.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)).postTranslate(playerX.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)) - playerPrevX.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)), playerY.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)) - playerPrevY.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)));

            }

            DrawView.pMatrixArray.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)).getValues(values);

            playerPrevX.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), playerX.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)));
            playerPrevY.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), playerY.get(Integer.toString(clientNum)));

            playerX.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), values[2]);
            playerY.put(Integer.toString(clientNum), values[5]);


            output.writeObject(playerX);
            output.flush();
            output.writeObject(playerY);
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("playerX OUT: " + playerX);
            System.out.println("playerX OUT: " + playerX);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        (findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).invalidate();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
```

The console prints the correct hashmap, but the server remains the way they were initiated

I've tested printing on the server side, and it prints the initiated hashmap values...

```
while ((inputObj = in.readObject()) != null) {

                System.out.println("input: " + inputObj);
```

Sorry for not being entirely clear, If anyone wants to help me I can post my full files somewhere.

I've tried moving the output.writeObject()s to the asynctask, but same thing.  Server handles the hashmaps fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization returns a *copy* of the object. Updating it locally doesn't magically update the copy at the peer where it came from.

NB Your read loop isn't correct. readObject() does not return null at end of stream. It throws an EOFException.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I know, the code isn't finished, i close the socket right now using tcpview.  I use writeObject to send the object to the server.  I know the server receives the object because i println on the server side, but it prints the initiated hashmap eg. {0=1.0,1=0.0} (initiated with hashmap.put("0",1)

Comment: You might need to look at ObjectOutputStream.reset().

Comment: About the loop though, should I stop the loop every time I don't receive input, or should I stop it when I'm certain no input should be received (such as sending null at onStop)